# What is the pythonic way to install a single python script

Tags: python, installation

I have a git repository with a single python script which I use for some task. I want to create a 'package' for this script and then install it. Previously I was using cmake to do this, but I'm wondering what the pythonic way of doing it is.

I tried using setuptools' `console_scripts` keyword argument, but that didn't work.

This script should get installed into some `./bin` directory.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here was to use the `scripts` keyword instead of `console_scripts`. my `setup.py` was then able to properly install the script.

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic way here would be to create an actual package https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/ and either building something like a .whl and installing that using `pip` or `conda` (whichever you use for managing your virtual environment), or publishing the package on PyPI for general use and easy installation on any machine with internet access.

Packaging a project is fairly standard and the linked documentation is official. Getting a package onto PyPI is fairly straightforward as well, although there are many options you can add to make the installation and the accompanying page nicer - there's many guides online on how to publish a package on PyPI, but none of then official documentation, so I suggest just searching for one.